# How can I route an image avoiding 404 error from Google Cloud?

Tags: laravel, google-app-engine, url, google-cloud-platform, routes

I'm developing an application web with Laravel, and I would like to use Google Cloud as a server. But I have troubles with the images.

In Laravel there's an option to link the "storage" folder with public folder.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

But I can't create this link in App Engine (Google Cloud) because I can't call command lines.

Otherwise, I created a route with a param who serve an image, but in Google Cloud, this return a 404 error because the URL ends with a file extension. (.jpg in my case)

Can I avoid this error with some handler in app.yaml?

Thank you very much.

(Sorry for my english)

```
Route::get('imatges/llocs/{filename}', function ($filename)
{
     $path = storage_path('app/public/llocs/' . $filename);

if (!File::exists($path)) {
    abort(404);
}

$file = File::get($path);
$type = File::mimeType($path);

$response = Response::make($file, 200);
$response->header("Content-Type", $type);

return $response;
});
```

Comment: As a suggestion. I would not store images (or any binary data) in Google App Engine Standard. I would store images on Google Cloud Storage. AE has space limitations. Plus Cloud Storage is cheaper and faster. I cannot answer your Laravel question.

Comment: You're right. The best solution, and my solution at the end, is store the images on Google Cloud Storage.